# ASP.NET MVC 5 / EF6 Many-to-Many

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I am pretty new to ASP.NET and I am trying to create a proper model for my little project.

Let me explain the concept first:
I want to create an ASP.NET Application to manage magazines and papers my users get. Also I want to assign users to the magazines. Simple enough. A Magazine/Paper can have multiple Users (Readers) and a User can have multiple Magazines he reads. That's why it is a many-to-many relationship to me.

I read through some Tutorials for code-first many-to-many relationships and as I understand, I will need a third class which includes both MagazineId and ReaderId. I want to ask you guys if this is the correct way:

**Magazine Class:**

```
[Table("MA_Magazine")]
public class Magazine
{
    public int MagazineId { get; set; }
    public string MagazineTitle { get; set; }
    public string Notice { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

**Reader Class:**

```
[Table("MA_Reader")]
public class Reader
{
    public int ReaderId { get; set; }
    public string ReaderName { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

**Subscription Class** (Third class, referencing both Magazine and Reader IDs):

```
public class Subscription
{
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public int MagazineId { get; set; }
    public int ReaderId { get; set; }
}
```

Is this correct so far?

Next step is to create the Viewmodel I guess:

```
public class viewAllModel
{
    public int MagazineId { get; set; }
    public string MagazineTitle { get; set; }
    public string Notice { get; set; }

    public int ReaderId { get; set; }
    public string ReaderName { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to list all Magazines with their Readers users and probably implement a Multiselect List to assign users to the magazine, where do I have to put the IEnumerable? Sorry that I am so confused about this, I bet there's a simple solution for this but as I said, I am pretty new to all of this and I don't completely understand the concept of Viewmodels yet.

I'd appreciate every comment and tipps of you. Thank you so much. :D

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET, this is Entity Framework.

Comment: Subscription could have a reference to Reader and Magazine instead of just ReaderId and MagazineId.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, thanks for your answer. Isn't the Viewmodel part asp.net related in terms of MVVM? But yeah, the model itself is EF.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ricardo mentioned, you should add references to the `Magazine` and `Reader` in `Subscription`, like so:

```
public class Subscription
{
    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public int MagazineId { get; set; }
    public int ReaderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MagazineId")]
    public Magazine Magazine { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ReaderId")]
    public Reader Reader { get; set; }
}
```

For assigning readers to magazines you could use a multi select or a list of checkboxes - have a page that allows you to assign `Magazine`s to a `Reader`. On this page you would display a list of all `Magazine`s to allow them to be selected, then create a `Subscription` object for each selected item.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer alxmitch. This helped a lot :D